Using Visual Studio to Create Columns for Fiscal year and period
I am new to visual studio and ssrs. My report I am making is not displaying the columns correctly. My code is displaying fy25p02 twice and I'm not sure why. It should be showing fy25p03 but it duplicates fy25p02.
My code that I am using is below:
="FY" & 24 + Ceiling(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, DateValue("9/01/2024"), Fields!sentonValue.Value) / 364)
& "P" & RIGHT("0" & (Ceiling((DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, DateValue("9/01/2024"), Fields!sentonValue.Value) Mod 364 + 1) / 28)), 2)
enter image description here
I'm not sure if its my math in determining the fiscal periods. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You'll need to show the data your expressions are based on and what you expect the output to be. EDIT your question Give samples of dates from sentonValue and what you expect to be returned. I'm assuming you are grouping by this expression? If not explain how it is being used and supply a screen shot of the report design including any row or column groups where this expression is being applied.

The crazy expression seems OK. What is the GROUP BY expression(s) for the Column Group? If it were the same as the display expression, there should only be one per FYP.
